# Passing query to website, then modify href

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am using a clickfunnels.com website which has a link at the bottom.
When people come to the website they should be able to attach a query to the URL like this: URL?ref=myreflink.

**The links href attribute has then to be modified to include the myreflink.**

I already managed to store the myreflink in a variable which then is called ref so I can output the value in an alert.

Now I want to change the link with this code but the link does not change. Can you please help?

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="mylink" onclick="changeLink();" target="_blank">google</a>

    <script>
    function changeLink() {
        var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
        window.open(
          link.href,
          '_blank'
        );
        link.innerHTML = "facebook";,
        link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com");
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

The result I see is: The page displays the link that has "http://www.google.com" as href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order, your change link function would be:

```
function changeLink() {
  var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
  link.innerHTML = "facebook";
  link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com");
  window.open(
    link.href,
    '_blank'
  );
  return false;
}
```

[Working link](https://plnkr.co/edit/D4Y3oKWz1SKMTnAtlXyE?p=preview)